# LocalStorage no mantiene los datos guardados al cerrar el navegador

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Estoy probando LocalStorage para guardar datos en la memoria del cliente y tengo un problema que no consigo resolver.

Guardo un objeto transformado en cadena por medio de setItem en LocalStorage y puedo acceder a este refrescando el navegador (Chrome 49.0) tranquilamente.
El problema viene cuando cierro el navegador los datos no se conservan.

functions.js

```
'use strict';

var obj           = {}; // Creamos un Obj en ambito global
var objsOnArray   = []; // Creamos un Array en ambito global
var arrayOnString = ''; // Creamos un String en ambito global

// Recibimos los valores del formulario
function save( uno, dos ) {

  // Los valores los agregamos al Obj
  obj = {
    "uno": uno.value,
    "dos": dos.value
  };

  // El Obj lo añadimos a un array que va a contener los objetos
  objsOnArray.push( obj );
  console.log( objsOnArray ); // Array[Obj, Obj, ...]

  // Transformamos este array de objetos a una cadena de texto para guardarla en local
  arrayOnString = JSON.stringify( objsOnArray );
  console.log( arrayOnString ); // String

  // Lo mandamos al LocalStorage
  localStorage.setItem( "all", arrayOnString );
  console.log( localStorage ); // String

  // Devolvemos el Obj para que se almacene en el ámbito global
  return objsOnArray;

}

function getLocal() {

  // accedemos a All en LocalStorage y lo reconvertimos en Obj
  objsOnArray = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("all") );
  console.log( objsOnArray ); // Obj

  // Devolvemos el Obj para almacenarlo en el ámbito global
  return objsOnArray;

}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<form name="form">

  <input name="uno" type="text">
  <input name="dos" type="text">

  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="save( uno, dos )">

</form>


<script src="functions.js"></script>
<script src="launch.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

launch.js

```
// Cuando esté cargado ejecuta...
window.onload = function() {

  // Si hay datos almacenados al abrír el navegador, muestralos
  if( localStorage.length > 0 ) {

    console.log('ONLOAD >>> Ya había datos en LocalStorage');

    return getLocal();

  } else {

    return console.log('ONLOAD >>> NO había ningún dato');

  }

};
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Esto puede ser un problema con la configuración del navegador. Si lo tienes configurado para que las cookies se borren al cerrar el navegador, es posible que también se borre el LocalStorage. ¿Has probado en otros navegadores?

Comment: Álvaro, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tenías toda la razón, tenía activas las cookies sólo hasta salir del navegador. Muchísimas gracias por hacerme ver lo que no veía.

Comment: Hola Pablo, puedes colocar tu código en la pregunta en lugar de dejarlo en una fuenta externa?

Comment: Hola Pablo, ¿Puedes colocar tu código en la pregunta en lugar de colocarlo en una fuente externa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto puede ser un problema con la configuración del navegador. Si lo tienes configurado para que las cookies se borren al cerrar el navegador, también se borrará el LocalStorage.

Para comprobar que no están deshabilitadas por defecto, o que no se van a borrar al cerrar el navegador:

1. Ve a la configuración de Chrome (*settings*),
2. De ahí ve a la configuración de privacidad (*privacy*)
3. Pulsa en el botón de Configuración de contenido... (*content settings...*)
4. Asegúrate de que el primer checkbox es el que está marcado:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Si no, el LocalStorage no se guardará, porque los navegadores lo deberían tratar de la misma manera que las cookies ([fuente](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html)).