# ¿Es seguro guardar un Array en localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Es seguro guardar un array en localstorage? he leido que uno puede convertir el array a un string y luego parsearlo pero que tan seguro es de que los datos permaneceran igual?

Una alternativa que estoy considerando es usar algo como:

```
localStorage.setItem("datoA", data[0]);
localStorage.setItem("datoB",  data[1]);
....
....
```

seria mucho mas codigo pero solo por seguridad

Comment: Con js, si te refieres al lado cliente, creo que nada es seguro, a excepción de que los datos estén encriptados o cosas por el estilo.

Comment: Si te refieres a la seguridad, `LocalStorage` es vulneable de varias formas, no deberias guardar informacion sensible ahi, sin importar la estructura de datos que elijas, la decision solo depende del tipo de informacion.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes almacenar array en el localStorage convirtiéndolos primero a JSON y volviéndolos a pasar a Array a leerlos.

```
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));

//...
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
```

Con esto te aseguras que los datos permanecerán igual a la hora de leerlos.

Solo ten en cuenta que como dice Diego, todo lo que guardes en localStorage puede ser visto por el usuario.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` es memoria del cliente, la cual es libre de ser consultada por el usuario cliente. Ten en cuenta que la información que guardes ahí será visible por cualquiera que sepa entrar a la consola del navegador, así que no debes guardar información sensible como contraseñas o números de tarjetas de crédito ahí, por lo menos no sin antes haberlas encriptado del lado del servidor.

Recuerda que en la web, para todo lo que quieras que haga el cliente debes proporcionar el código fuente (si no quieres usar [`applets`](http://www.logicaalternativa.com/%EF%BB%BFjava-versus-javascript-reflexiones/)), por lo tanto, quien sepa presionar `CTRL+U` podrá leer tu lógica. Aprende a separar las tareas de tu sitio y evalúa si la información es sensible o no y si lo que estás sirviendo en el cliente es crítico para la operación.

Comment: El uso de **applets** esta en desuso, al usarlo solo habría que tener los mismos recaudos que cuando usas cookies en una app. No se quien almacenaría contraseñas y menos números de tarjetas (ni siquiera de lado del servidor), aunque aclaro para algo que comunmente se usa es para almacenar token de autentificación, ya que es la unica formar de poder trabajar con apis REST. Lo que no se a ciencia cierta es si los complementos pueden leer los datos de localStorage sumpogo que si

Comment: Por supuesto que los **applets** son tecnología arcaica, y lo de almacenar contraseñas o datos así de sensibles no dudes que haya gente (inexperta) que lo llegue a intentar. Mi respuesta va orientada al título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es seguro, en cuanto a que el dato no se pierde a menos que lo borres ( aunque dependerá de la  [configuración del navegador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6079/localstorage-no-mantiene-los-datos-guardados-al-cerrar-el-navegador)), comúnmente se usa para guardar tokens de autenticación, datos de preferencias del usuario, etc., recuerda que esos datos se compartiran entre todas las secciones abiertas que apunten a dicho host en el navegador, alternativamente puedes usar **sessionStorage** es similar solo que los datos son persistentes por ventana, en cambio localstorage sera unico y permanecera hasta que lo borres explicitamento.